# Closing an Android application after starting it with FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK

Tags: android, android-service

I have two Android applications A and B.  App A carries out some tasks which need to be secure, while app B is used for more typical app things (UI and the like).  App A is relevant here mainly because it has a launcher Activity, while app B doesn't.  To a user, it should really just look like only one app is running.

From a Service in app A, I will sometimes send requests to a Service in app B to perform some action, like this:

```
public class AppAService extends Service {
   //... more code ...
   public void makeRequest(Intent request){
     request.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.mydomain.B", "com.mydomain.B.AppBService"));
     startService(request);

   }
}
```

When I get these requests in the service in app B, I sometimes want to get some input from the user, or display progress (for example, if I'm going to download a file, I may want to make sure the user is ok with that), so I might launch a UI Activity like this:

```
public class AppBService extends Service {
    //... more code ...
    public void askUser(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(AppBService.this, UIActivity.class);
        //Need a new task since we are starting from a service
        intent.setFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

My problem is, I don't want the user to be able to ever navigate back to UIActivity by opening recent tasks; it's really just supposed to be a temporary thing to let them know something important is going on in the background.  I have tried using `System.exit(0)` in the UIActivity class after it has finished getting input, but this doesn't seem to work (and even if it did I would be hesitant to use it).  Here is the relevant function from UIActivity where I broadcast a response after the user has given relevant input:

```
public void sendResponse(){
    Intent response = new Intent();
    response.setAction("com.mydomain.action.RESPONSE");
    sendBroadcast(response);
    finish();
    //System.exit(0); //using this breaks things AND the user can still open the activity from recent tasks
}
```

I've also set the `noHistory` option to true within my manifest file for UIActivity, but that doesn't work either.  One thing I've done which works ok is to start the UIActivity again after everything else has finished with an Intent action that I detect and call `System.exit(0)`.  I can resort to this if I have to, but it seems like there *has* to be a better way.

Basically I just want a way to pop up some simple UI from my service, then prevent the user from navigating back to that Activity after they have given the necessary input.  I considered adding the UI elements to the window manager from an AsyncTask within the Service, but it seems really sloppy to do it that way.  Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you tried with flag Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS?

Comment: Wow, now I feel stupid.  That works, thank you so much!